# Find extreme emotions with Python Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, data-science, sentiment-analysis

Basically I want to find Twitter comments that are **very** positive, and ignore those that are just a little positive. The sentiment analysis methods I found only tell if the sentiment is positive/neutral/negative, but don't say how positive or negative is the comment.

How could this be done with Python?

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html

Comment: You mean outputting the prediction probability?

Comment: @yuRa, yes that would be sufficient.

Comment: You can just output the probability of the predictions. Depends on what are you using. I would recommend BERT.

Comment: In your case its a binary classification problem so you would ideally get an array of 2 values with the prediction probability on each class. Just access them using indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, u could use a pretrained model - `BERT`, that comes with emmbeding etc.
U can see [here](https://www.kaggle.com/praveengovi/classify-emotions-in-text-with-bert) an exact implementation using `transformers` in pytorch.

Also, check out `SPARK NLP` [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop/blob/master/tutorials/streamlit_notebooks/SENTIMENT_EN_EMOTION.ipynb) for emotion detection.